# Component Not Rendering with React Router and React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-bootstrap

Trying to get webpage to render the Resources.js component. However, the only thing that changes is the url route (<www.examplesite/resources>). The home page component remains on screen, and is never replaced by the resources component. Have tried using a Nav.Item tag instead of Nav.Link tag. Have also tried using Link Container to wrap Nav.Link and Nav.Item, and doesn't work.`enter code here`

```
      import React from 'react';
      import { BrowserRouter, Route, NavLink, Switch, withRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
      import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
      import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
      import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';
      import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
      import Home from './components/Home';
      import Resources from './components/Resources';


      class App extends Component {

        render () {
          return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route to='/' exact render={() => (<Home/>)} />
          <Route to='/resources' exact render={() => (<Resources/>)} />
        </Switch>
        <Navbar id='make_gray' bg="light" expand="lg" fixed='top'>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav"/>
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto">
            <NavDropdown title={'Link Dropdown'} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
              <Nav.Link as={Link} exact to="/resources">link to resources</Nav.Link>
              <NavDropdown.Divider />
              <Nav.Link as={Link} exact to="/resources">link to resources</Nav.Link>
            </NavDropdown>
          </Nav>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </BrowserRouter>
      </React.Fragment>
          )
      }
      }
```

Comment: `Route` takes a `path` prop, ie. `path="/resources"`. After fixing that does your router render the resources component if you manually type in the URL in the address bar?

Comment: No, @DrewReese it still doesn't render.

Comment: Interesting. Mind trying to duplicate this snippet into a *running* codesandbox to live debug here?

Comment: hey @DrewReese it looks like I had to change the other to attributes in my routes to paths. Once I changed all of them it worked. Thanks for the contribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to replace all "to" attributes in my Route Components to "path" attributes.